# Web App Database Views

Tags: database, web-applications, oracle11g, view

I have a fairly small sized CRUD web application with some inference reports. The reports are generated using DROOLS and Oracle database views. I find it difficult to figure out exactly what the views are doing and stand almost no chance in modifying the view (some views are around 100 lines of query code). Is this the best practice, storing the data items of interest in a view? I'm not a greatly experienced database person, but I'm trying to figure out if an architecture change is needed or if I just need to dig into databases so that I can understand the database views better.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using database views as such. As you have described, they are encapsulating some complex queries. Where else would you put those same queries? Note that you're not storing anything in a view. It's more of a virtual table.

Comment: I would find it simpler to include the logic in the java back end. I would specify a simpler query during a transaction. Note that I'm using the Grails framework, Hibernate, and GORM. I would like to write  service methods for some complex queries and just call those as needed. Is there anything wrong with that? I understand there's probably a performance implication, but from what I've found testing my web-app, the database views are running pretty slow anyways.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that. With modern databases there's no serious performance impact of doing it, as they automatically optimise frequently-called queries. So there's no big performance improvement from using views or stored procedures. Although if they are 'materialized views', then they are caching the results, and as such are likely to be significantly faster than code in your application.

Comment: fyi - If they're not materialized views, then they have no indexes, so they could be incredibly slow compared to your services calling well-indexed tables directly.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using named queries in my domain classes to make the code more manageable. I also broke a lot of the views into smaller queries so that I could pinpoint a bottle neck and apply a cache. I think it does wonders having the queries in the domain class as far as code management and helped me figure out bottlenecks